# Rename files with non-utf8 characters using detox

Tags: filenames, character-encoding

I am trying to use `detox` in the following way

```
detox -s utf_8-only -r -v -n
```

to detect invalid filenames on my system. The command performs mostly ok. Unfortunately it falsely detects also German Umlauts (äöü etc.) which I would like to keep. Note that they are in utf-8 encoding. Can I alter the command such (e.g. by adding filters) that it will ignore filenames with Umlauts?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done; see the `detox.tbl(5)` man page for an explanation of the translation tables and `/usr/share/detox/*.sample` for some examples.

Comment: When answering questions, please post the relevant information so future searchers have easy access to what will actually fix the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Man pages are lacking good example [detox man](https://man.archlinux.org/man/detox.1.en) [detoxrc man](https://man.archlinux.org/man/detoxrc.5.en) [detoxtbl man](https://man.archlinux.org/man/detox.tbl.5.en)

I created my own table (copy example file)

```
cp /usr/share/detox/safe.tbl /etc/detox/music.tbl
```

Edit /etc/detox/music.tbl

```
# chars to leave alone
0x2e        .

# nuke these chars
0x27        '' # '

# Chars to translate to _
0x7c        _   # |
```

Modify config /etc/detox/detoxrc, adding this section:

```
sequence "music" {
    utf_8;
    safe {filename "/etc/detox/music.tbl";};
};
```

Run inside a folder of music... if your happy with the results, remove '-n' no-act flag.

```
user@host: /mnt/tunes/2017 # detox -s music -r -v -n ./
```

You may have to combine tables and remove duplicates for the best results